# How do I use python with HTML?

Tags: python, html

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible but I'm struggling to find alternatives.

```
a = {a very long dictionary that has every country and its area in km²}
b = list(a.values())
c = input("Enter an area (km²): ")

try: b.append(int(c))
except: print("That's not an number!")
b.sort( reverse=True)
d = len(b)-b.index(int(c))-1
f = b[b.index(int(c))+1]

g = 0
for k,v in a.items():
    if v == f:
        g = k

e = "An area of {} km² is larger than {} countries. The largest country that could fit inside that area is {}.".format(str(c),str(d),g)
print(e)
```

What I'm trying to find is a way to somehow make this compatible with HTML so that I can upload this to a webpage rather than have to use VS to access the code. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Try out [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/), there you'll have a builtin webserver. The input needs to be done via parameters or a form field though.

Comment: you will need to create a website in python. You can use some framework like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Whichever you feel comfortable with. I usually use Django, but for such a small tesk django will be an overkill, but in Django you get things done much faster. Website with just this much functionality will take 5 minutes. Also for performing just this much task you don't need a python server. You can implement this using javascript much easily without having to go through the troubles of setting up a web server

Comment: @Jan I tried using flask and I've been confused on how it works and how to implement it. Is there some kind of example or guide I can follow based on a similar situation?